# Deploying angular2 project on go daddy server

Tags: angular, web-hosting, angular-cli

I have an angular-2 project running on my local host. I want to deploy it to GoDaddy server. I can't install node, npm on GoDaddy server. So my question is how can I run my angular-2 project on GoDaddy server.
Thanks

Comment: use universal webpack to bundle your project into one js file with index,html. you can upload that as normal html and js file. if backend is in node.js go for digital ocean or heroku.

Answer (score 16):

Install Angular CLI if you don't have it already.

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Then build using the command -

```
ng build
```

This will create a /dist directory with the production build of your application. Just copy the contents of /dist to your hosting provider (using FTP, SCP etc.).

Refer - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: I have /dist files with me and I uploaded it in public_html folder but I don't see my app ruuning. I ran the command ng build --prod --env=prod.

Comment: index.html is opening showing Loading but the components are not getting loaded actually

Comment: You can try to check if there are any errors during page load. In chrome developer tools. Especially check for 404 errors in the network tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there were issues with <base href> tag

Comment: can you tell me exactly where I have to keep /dist files

Comment: Once you upload the files, you must edit index.html and remove
  <base href="/"> in order for the application to not get 404 errors

Comment: at the time of build --prod what should be the base href

Answer (score 11):

1.If your project is completed then build your project using

ng build --prod

2.Go to your project/dist
Copy your Build Project which is automatically created and paste it to desktop -> Right Click on that pasted project folder -> Add to zip .

3.Go to your godaddy account -> profile -> my Products ->Starter Linux Hosting with cPanel ->manage ->cpanel Admin -> file manager .

4. Click on public_html folder .
5. click on Upload -> select file -> select your Zip folder -> click on link "Go Back to "home/frurugf45/public_html" .

And your Angular file uploaded on go godaddy server

Comment: What are the steps after this? I have done the above mentioned steps. Now, how can I launch the website?

Comment: after that decompress that and save everything.  then go to browser and put your url there.

Comment: Thanks anand, had figured it out though :)

Answer (score 6):

Run `ng build --prod` don't forget to use `--prod`. It means build the application in Production mode. It's performance of application is faster than ng build.

Comment: This is the real answer; the accepted answer is not _incorrect_, simply _incomplete_.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$ ng build --prod` if your application is ready for production. It will reduce the size and increase **speed** of your application on the web. 
`$ ng build` **VS.** `$ ng build --prod` 
My small application went from 23mb to 2mb.

Loading time on 3G network: 8 seconds **FAIR**, 28% visitor loss due to loading time
**VS.**
Loading time on 3G network: 4 seconds **GOOD**, 10% visitor loss due to loading time

[image]

**VS.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

manojtc is corect...run npm build then copy all the files/folders from the dist directory to your website (or sub-domain) root folder...works like a charm..have it working in a GoDaddy Windows sub-domain